# Conditionally prevent swiping for angular UI Carousel bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, angular-ui

I have a custom carousel that I extend from angularUI carousel bootstrap carousel. I added ng-touch so it supports swiping. I also added a custom swipe function on top of the original prev() and next() function from the bootstrap, so in my DOM the ng-swipe will look like this:

```
<carousel ... ng-swipe-left="myCustomSwipe(); next()" ng-swipe-right="myCustomSwipe();prev()"> content here </carousel>
```

My question is, I want to make my carousel not looping. This can be done easily by hiding the left / right arrows when I reach the end of the loop. But for swiping, I don't know how to do it since even though I don't do anything inside my customSwipe() function, it will still call next() or prev() from the original bootstrap.

How do I prevent the prev() and next() in swiping? Do I have to override the ng-swipe-left and ng-swipe-right? Thanks.

Comment: Can you put some logic code functions() etc your angualr controller

Comment: what do you mean? I added some logic code functions to my angular controller but it will call the next() and prev() after :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question. I ended up have to override the original prev and next functions from the angular UI carousel bootstrap. To do this, I need to access the isolated scope of the angular UI bootstrap. Here's a question that helps me to do that:

[AngularJS - Hook into Angular UI Bootstrap - Carousel Custom Next()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337230/angularjs-hook-into-angular-ui-bootstrap-carousel-custom-next)

Hope this helps others who have similar intention.